# Route to page /:permalink from root rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `PagesController` in rails and each page has a permalink, which can't change... 
I'd like to route to that from "/", i.e "/contact" instead of "/pages/contact".

(It's not an option to use `get "/contact", to: "pages#show"`)

Comment: Just curious as to why using `get 'contact', to: 'pages#show'` is not an option. Depending on why could yield some possible alternatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set `path` for `resource pages`:

```
resources :pages, :path=>"/"  #,:only=>[:show]
```

And set other routes like `get '/res'=> "ctl#act"` before above `pages`.